# What plugin is Google Chrome blocking?

Tags: google-chrome

In Google Chrome, I have my options set so that all plugins are click-to-play.  For the most part, this works fine.  However, sometimes, Chrome will show the [image: Chrome plugin blocked icon] on a page that I can't find a plugin on, even by looking through the source html of the page.  There's no element on the page that I can see that is asking me to click it to play the plugin.  Is there a way to identify exactly what plugin(s) Google is asking me to play?

I'm aware that I can go through and disable extensions to see if one of those is causing it, but in general, it'd be nice to know *what* I'm enabling when I run plugins, so I'd still like to know if there is a way to identify them.

Note:  These settings can be obtained by the following steps:

1. `about:flags` > disable `Block all third-party cookies`
2. options > Under the Hood > Plugins > Click To Play

Comment: Any clues if you right-click the icon and choose "Inspect Element"?

Comment: @AlEverett, there's no element in the page that I can see to do that to.  Just the icon in the omnibar.

Comment: Ah. Hmmm...Got an URL I could try it out on?

Comment: Is "Click to Play" in the Beta channel? I can't find it in 11 stable. (I know I could go to about:///.)

Comment: @AlEverett, blanking on what url I've seen it on, will updated when I figure it out.

Comment: @muntoo, I run the stable channel...

Comment: @muntoo -> Enable click to play from Wrench -> Options -> Under the hood/bonnet -> Content Settings -> Plugins

Comment: @Sathya Do you mean `Block all`? I only have two options. I have it on `Run automatically (recommended)` at the moment. On the other hand, I see `Click to play` under `about:flags`

Comment: @muntoo you should have click to play http://i.imgur.com/GBMuJ.png if not, check `about:flags` and see if it's enabled there.

Comment: @Rebecca, is there an IFrame in the page?

Comment: FWIW: I was able to get the icon to appear on the Google Voice page.

Comment: That said, I don't see a way to figure out what's being blocked.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to find them by looking through the `embed` tags and perhaps the newer `canvas` tags.

1. Start the **Developer tools** from the **Wrench** -> **Tools** menu.
2. Search for `embed` and `canvas`, enumerate through the found tags.
3. Repeat the search for both the Elements and Scripts tab.

In my case I have [Cooliris](http://www.cooliris.com/) installed, and apparently thanks to you I have just discovered that it always loads:

[image]

<sub>PS: I'm using Firefox 6.0a1 as a main browser, but Google Chrome and IE9 as a back-up for when Firefox 6.0a1 breaks.</sub>

---

However, if enabling the plug-in is allowed, you could simply open **Task Manager** from the **Tools** menu and check the latest plug-in(s) that was/were launched. Which indicates what plug-in(s) the site ran.

[image]

Comment: Yup, as mentioned in the question, I have looked through the source code trying to identify what it could be and that didn't help.

Comment: @Rebecca: Can you try to do the same query in the Scripts tab? Perhaps it's loaded outside the DOM. Or it's removed after it was inserted, in my case there is also an `embed` in one of the scripts to insert Cooliris code.

Comment: yes, that's possible.  But please not that the focus on my question is an easy way to identify what I'm running when I click to run all plugins in the page.  Searching through potentially many js requests is not "easy", and definitely not for someone who isn't comfortable with code.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't any native way to do that @Rebecca, there isn't really functionality to get plugins information. Perhaps there might be a Web Developer kind of extension that allows you to list them, or perhaps you could see if [enabling logging](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) allows you to see it, but that would be an annoying way to check it. And while it indeed goes into the code, the Search box will look through all the lines in all the scripts, and looking at the `type` attribute inside the `embed`s you find can quickly reveal what plugin it could be.

Comment: @Rebecca: Updated my answer which a suggestion for when you can run the plug-in...